# Rsync only particular files and directory that contain those files

Tags: bash, synchronization, rsync

Supposed I have directory structure like

```
src/
src/a/
src/a/1.ocf  
src/a/1.pdf  
src/a/1.txt
src/b/
src/b/2.ocf
src/b/2.pdf
src/b/2.xls
src/c/
src/c/3.doc
src/c/3.ocf
src/c/3.txt
src/d/
```

Then, I just want to synchronize only files with extension *.txt.  So, I tried to use command like:

```
#rsync -avvH --include="*/" --include="*.txt" --exclude="*" src/ dst/
sending incremental file list
./
a/
a/1.txt
b/
c/
c/3.txt
d/
```

Unfortunately, this command not only synchronize *.txt file but also all directory. I don't want directory 'b' and 'd' be synchronized because it not contain file *.txt

Is there simple way to do that?

Comment: Use the `-m` option to prune empty directories…

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The option you're looking for is `-m` to prune empty directories:

```
rsync -avvHm --include="*/" --include="*.txt" --exclude="*" src/ dst/
```